# Oracle - PCRE to Oracle REGEX

Tags: regex, oracle, pcre

I want to extract everything after the first occurrence and the second occurrence of '@':

1331@**iwantthis**@3ad44@2

In PCRE I would do this like that (at least for the given example):

```
(?<=\d{4}\@).\w+
```

Since Oracle DBMS does not support PCRE, how can I extract the desired substring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you may use

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('1331@iwantthis@3ad44@2', '[^@]+', 1, 2)
```

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/OWXL20754).

This will extract the *second* occurrence (as the *occurrence* argument is set to `2`) starting from the first symbol in the string (as the *position* argument is set to `1`) of a `[^@]+` pattern that matches one or more chars other than `@` char as many as possible.

See more details on the [`REGEXP_SUBSTR` reference page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm).

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the expression that you want to match in a capturing group and then unwrap the look-behind and then just extract the value of the capturing group with the 6th argument of `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('1331@iwantthis@3ad44@2', '\d{4}\@(.\w+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | REGEXP_SUBSTR('1331@IWANTTHIS@3AD44@2','\D{4}\@(.\W+)',1,1,NULL,1) |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | iwantthis                                                          |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ceef89ab6640acd6ed66f7c64782e511)*